# Laravel not showing images form storage on shared server

Tags: php, laravel, image, symlink

My images are not showing up on site. I get 404

Symlink function is disabled but I used this instead:

`ln -s /home/USERNAME/my_app/storage/app/public /home/USERNAME/public_html/storage`
to create it.

Url on site looks good https://my_app.com/storage/logo.png

Binded public path to public_html

```
  $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return '/home/my_app/public_html';
});
```

I tried to get images in these two ways:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->getFirstMedia()->getUrl() }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

And tired with asset()

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($post->getFirstMedia()->getUrl()) }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

But still nothing.
The src link looks good https://my_app.com/storage/logo.png but no image, just 404.

SOLUTION:

/home/USERNAME/my_app/ folder permissions were 700, changed to 755 and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

If your **public** directory name is **public_html** in laravel project's root then you must have to change the links key value to in `config/filesystems.php`

```
'links' => [
    base_path('public_html/storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

You can create code in route file to run laravel command in your cpanel.

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
   Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```

If you still can't create symlink then here is the protected way to get your files from the storage folder
You can **Get route** to get files from storage directly.

```
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename) {
    $path = storage_path('public/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404); // return 404 page
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

Comment: Well I can't use storage:link , it is disabled on my shared hosting... So I need to create it manually , but it doesn't work properly? The link is created , on cpanel file manager I can click on it and it goes to the right folder but when I try via link it doesn't work , i get laravels 404.

Comment: Can you show me exactly how you trying to access from storage?

Comment: <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->getFirstMedia()->getUrl() }}" alt="Card image cap">
And tired with asset() 
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset($post->getFirstMedia()->getUrl()) }}" alt="Card image cap">
The url looks good to me but it doesn't work. 
On one shared server it works fine but on other it doesn't. Same hosting, different account, same app. 
The difference is on one symlink is enabled.

Comment: @DzoniPfc Check the edited answer. Added code to get a file using the route. let me know if it is usefull or not

Comment: Well the problem were the folder permissions... /home/user/my_app folder was on 700 and I changed it to 755 and now it works fine! 
Thanks for the help!